# Why did Davy Jones stab Will Turner thereby risking his life?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

During *Pirates of the Carribbean: At World's End*, the following exchange occurs:

> **Jones:** Ah. Love. A dreadful bond. And yet, so easily severed. Tell me, William Turner. Do you fear death?
>
> **Jack:** Do you? Heady tonic, holding life and death in the palm of one's hand.
>
> **Jones:** You're a cruel man, Jack Sparrow.
>
> **Jack:** Cruel is a matter of perspective.
>
> **Jones:** Is it?

Then Davy Jones stabbed Will Turner even though his life was at stake.
Why did he stab Will risking his life? He seemed a very clever and tactical captain. Still did this. What was the motive?

Comment: Why was his life in danger ?

Comment: Because his heart was on Jack's hand. @JanardanS

Comment: I think he knew that Jack wouldn't do anything...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel yes.. I think that too... it could be.. I wanted expert opinion to be sure... thanks btw

Comment: Even tactical people make mistakes, specially in the heart of battle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**He knew that Jack wouldn't do anything**

Davy Jones walking away after he stabbed Will showed that he was confident that Jack wouldn't anything. Altough it seems that Jack had everything under control, not even Jack knew what to do.

Remember that earlier in the movie Jack was talking to himself deciding if he was gonna stab the heart or not.